# Dividing a map into zones based on latitude

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude

I'm new to QGIS and I'm trying to divide a map of the world based on latitude. The final result, I need a shapefile or a raster file where multiple zones are created based on latitudinal zones. Is there a way to do this on QGIS?

Zones are required based on the following categorization (horizontal strips):
50N to 90N
30N to 50N
10N to 30N
-10S to 10N
-30S to -10S
50S to -30S
-90S to -50S –

Comment: What input data have you got?

Comment: I have a base map (vector) of the world from GADM that has been cleaned based on the areas I need. The CRS is ESRI:54009 - World_Mollweide. Other than that I wasn't sure of what else I'll need.

Comment: What sort of zones do you want? Just a grid? Or something else?

Comment: Zones based on the following categorisation (so horizontal strips): 50N to 90N
30N to 50N
10N to 30N
-10S to 10N
-30S to -10S
50S to -30S
-90S to -50S

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification.

Comment: There are several tutorials on how to do this online. Splitting vector polygons is an extremely basic GIS task.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Create Intersection Layer** To create the clipping layer you can use a custom python script like:

```py
# Define Zones
zones = [
    [90,50,"Region 1"],
    [50,30,"Region 2"],
    [30,10,"Region 3"],
    [10,-10,"Region 4"],
    [-10,-30,"Region 5"],
    [-30,-50,"Region 6"],
    [-50,-90,"Region 7"]
]

# Create temporary layer
regions = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "regions", "memory")

# Start edit session on temporary layer
regions.startEditing()
dataProvider = regions.dataProvider()
dataProvider.addAttributes([QgsField("region", QVariant.String)])

# Loop Zones and create Features
for zone in zones:
    polygon = QgsFeature()
    pts = [
        QgsPointXY(-180,zone[0]),
        QgsPointXY(180,zone[0]),
        QgsPointXY(180,zone[1]),
        QgsPointXY(-180,zone[1])
    ]
    polygon.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([pts]))
    polygon.setAttributes([zone[2]])
    dataProvider.addFeatures([polygon])
    
# Commit changes and add layer to map
regions.commitChanges()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(regions)
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/fC8DBdCH) you find the layer as geojson.

**2) Intersect World data by Custom Layer**
Then you would need to create an intersection of your world data with the newly created layer using the `Intersection` tool (Vector --> Geoprocessing Tools --> Intersection).

[image]

**3) Export in EPSG:54009**
To project your clipped data into your desired CRS make a right click on your intersected layer --> Export --> Save Feature As --> Change the CRS accordingly.

**4) Style**
For a nice styling I would recommend to categorize the newly created layer by the region attribute.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernd for the comprehensive answer! Just wondering if the intersection layer can be created on QGIS itself.

Comment: That's happening at step 2.